# error: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, undefined-behavior

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int n;
    printf("input number:\t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

It runs until the scanf and then it just crashes:

```
1234875770417Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've looked at the other posts that are similar to this, but none of them solve my problem.

Comment: You allocated memory only for one object of the type int  int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)); So n may not be greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer in this declaration

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

allocates memory only for one object of the type `int`. So in this case `n` may not be greater than 1.

You should write at least

```
int main( void ) {
    int n;
    printf("input number:\t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *arr = malloc( n * sizeof(int));
    //...
```

Also it would be better to declare the variable n as having the type `unsigned int` instead of the type `int`.

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is an updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;

    printf( "input a non-negative number:\t" );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    int *arr = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        scanf( "%d", &arr[i] );
    }

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    free( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
input a non-negative number:    10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: int *arr = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
so basically this is n elements and not only one such as: 
int *arr = malloc( sizeof( int ) ); ?

Comment: @Mytavaz Yes the memory is allocated for n objects of the type int.

Answer (score 0):

Since you allocated memory only for one integer using `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));` and you are trying to store `n` elements into that so it crashes.

First scan the `n` value and then allocate memory for `n` elements using `malloc()`.

```
int main() {
        int n;
        printf("input number:\t");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int *arr = malloc(n*sizeof(*arr)); /*it's generic it allocated memory for any type */
        if(arr == NULL) {
           printf("memory allocation failed \n");
           exit(0);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%d", arr[i]);
        }
        free(arr);
        return 0;
}
```